# How to handle a join of a variable number of incoming?

Tags: django, django-viewflow

Is there a way to handle  "partial Joins" in viewflow?

For example: an order is received, and after checking and booking-in then each line item is  manufactured in parallel (`Split`). Normally these would all join before the customer required-by date, and then the order will be dispatched with everything in one shipment. But sometimes there is an unexpected hold on one or more items because of a manufacturing issue that could not be known at the time the order is accepted.

Is there a way to describe a  "join" of the items that are ready for shipment to be joined into a partial shipment, and leaving the other manufacturing tasks to complete in however long it takes  and be joined into another shipment later?

Or is this too complex for viewflow, and should I be looking at several separate business processes?  One process to book in an order which starts  N manufacturing processes, and then code run by Celery to pick out  completed manufacturing which needs to be dispatched,  either because everything for that order  is ready, or because the order requires partial shipment.

I'm still teaching myself viewflow and working through the cookbook examples (and also Celery) so apologies if I have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yep,from BPMN point of view the proposed implementation sounds like an anti pattern. A process should be designed with main goal to finish, probably with spawning other process instances.

But generally with Viewflow you can simple subclass and provide custom behavior to any node.

You could check custom node [sample](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/customnode/nodes.py) and [join node](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/nodes/join.py#L33) code for the reference.